# How do I change the innerHTML of an element using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to change `innerHTML` of a `div`, when I click on the button. I don't know why, but instead of getting an error, or getting the expected result it deletes to content and replacing it with `"[object Object]"`.

How can I get it work?

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './components/login.js';
import SignIn from './components/signin';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  function LoginOnClick(){
    document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = <SignIn />;
  }
  return (
    <div className="container" id="wrapper">
      <button onClick={LoginOnClick}>Login</button>
      <Login />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `innerHTML` must be set to a `string` value. Instead, you're setting it to an *`Object`*.

Comment: We know it won't work....you can't set an object as innerHTML. You should not be using `document.getElementById(id)` anywhere in your app

Comment: How should I fix it?

Comment: By changing what gets rendered  based on state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With react you don’t have to set the innerHtml to do this, instead the more typical way is to have internal state in your component and conditionally render your SignIn component based off that. To use state the component either needs to be class or use hooks, classes are more traditional so I changed the component to be a class.

To make a class a react component you need to extend the class with the React.Component, this is because react components have lots of internal behaviours that you need to include with your class for it to be considered a component.

So

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signIn: false,
    };

    this.LoginOnClick = () => {
      this.setState({ signIn: true });
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.signIn) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <SignIn />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className=“container”>
        <button onClick={this.LoginOnClick}>Login</button>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm getting this error:  Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Comment: sorry, yeah I edited the code, try again now and let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: Line 33:  'LoginOnClick' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Oh yeah. It’s on this now

Comment: Line 32:  'LoginOnClick' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Can you explain me what is "class App extends React.Component" mean?

Comment: Why would you define a function on a class in the constructor

Comment: Oh I was just doing that because it’s the old school way of doing it that will work for everyone, the other way works as well. Different ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [`Hooks`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (Added n React 16.8).

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Login from './components/login.js';
import SignIn from './components/signin';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [signIn, setSignIn] = useState(false); 
  return (
    <div className="container" id="wrapper">
      {signIn ? <SignIn /> : <> //This is React Fragments syntax
      <button onClick={() => setSignIn(true)}>Login</button>
      <Login />
      </>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
import {useState} from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");
  setTxt(<p> 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.' </p>);

  return(
    <div>
      {txt}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```